# When and How Keras calculate metrics for each batch of samples?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I was seeing how Keras custom metrics working, and calculation doesn't match between `tf.print` in metric function and callback print of `model.fit`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf  # tf2.4.1
import numpy as np
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,))
)
def my_metric_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred)
    loss =  tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)
    tf.print(y_true.shape, y_pred.shape, loss, tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference))
    return loss
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=[my_metric_fn])
x = np.random.rand(4,1)
y = x ** 2
history = model.fit(x=x, y=y, batch_size=2, epochs=2)
print(history.history)
```

Output (formatted for a better readability)

```
Epoch 1/2
TensorShape([2, 1]) TensorShape([2, 1]) [9.79962078e-06 0.0534314588] 0.02672063
1/2 [==============>...............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0267 - my_metric_fn: 0.0267
TensorShape([2, 1]) TensorShape([2, 1]) [0.0397406667 0.179955378] 0.109848022
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0544 - my_metric_fn: 0.0544

Epoch 2/2
TensorShape([2, 1]) TensorShape([2, 1]) [0.0392204635 0.0521505736] 0.0456855185
1/2 [==============>...............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0457 - my_metric_fn: 0.0457
TensorShape([2, 1]) TensorShape([2, 1]) [0.177408844 2.45939535e-08] 0.088704437
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.0600 - my_metric_fn: 0.0600
{'loss': [0.06828432530164719, 0.06719497591257095], 'my_metric_fn': [0.06828432530164719, 0.06719497591257095]}
```

See a printed loss of a batch in an above output.

Epoch 1/2 1/2 tf.print: 0.02672063, and model.fit: 0.0267. OK.
Epoch 1/2 2/2 tf.print: 0.109848022, but model.fit: 0.0544. Not OK.

How can I understand these match and mismatch? Where did 0.0544 come from?

Comment: is there anything that I miss?

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I found It needs more time to investigate and find out the cause and an answer. Answer might be detailed report by diving into ```model.fit``` method. A discussion goes over a github issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47366. Until everything gets clear  I feel like to keep this question without accepted answer so that everybody has a chance to dig into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In keras, the training loss/metric is calculated at the end of each epoch as the mean of loss/metric in each batch. so in your case:

```
EPOCH 1: (0.02672063 + 0.109848022) / 2 = 0.068284326
EPOCH 2: (0.0456855185 + 0.088704437) / 2 = 0.06719497775
```

which correspond to:

```
history.history['loss'] ==> [0.06828432530164719, 0.06719497591257095]
```

Comment: Yes, I know. How did  0.0544 come from? Thanks!

Comment: @Watanabe.N which is your tf version?

Comment: @Watanabe.N sorry it's 2.4.1 (as u reported and as I suspected)... With TF 2.3.0 this doesn't happen as u can see here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12Ta4ipyO7vpkiWNX_iUkLiHsmXM_79iR?usp=sharing

Comment: Ah, really. I read your notebook and it makes sense to me. I confirmed on my environment with tf2.3.1 on colab. In my case 
 with tf2.4.1, (0.02672063+0.109848022)/2 = 0.068284326, which isn't equal to 0.0544. This is strange. I'm gonna make an issue.